# POST method for a controller stopped working when I deployed my site to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, web-development-server

I have a [React app](https://highgear.netlify.app) deployed on Netlify, and its [API backend](https://highgear.herokuapp.com/) (Ruby on Rails + PostgreSQL) deployed on Heroku. The backend worked completely fine on LocalHost. However, when I deployed it to Heroku, one of my three controllers stopped working correctly. All of my other controllers and their methods are functional, so I don't quite get why this specific method should fail. `Comment.create(...)` on the Rails console also doesn't seem to work.

comment.rb (model):

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :User
  belongs_to :ForumThread
end
```

comments_controller.rb (controller):

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    #GET /Comments [Get all comments for a specific thread]
    def index
        @Comments = Comment.where("comments.forumthread_id = ?", params[:forum_thread_id])
        render json: @Comments
    end

    #GET /Comments/:id [Get a specific comment by its ID]
    def show
        @Comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        render json: @comment
    end

    #POST /Comments [Create a comment]
    def create
        @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
        if @comment.save
            render json: @comment
        else
            render error: {error: "Error in creating comment"}, status: 400
        end
    end

    #PUT /Comments/:id [Update a comment]
    def update
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        if @comment
            @comment.update(comment_params)
            render json: {message: "Comment successfully updated"}, status: 200
        else
            render error: {error: "Error in updating comment"}, status: 400
        end
    end

    #DELETE /Comments/:id [Delete a comment]
    def destroy
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        if @comment
            @comment.destroy
            render json: {message: "Comment successfully deleted"}, status: 200
        else
            render error: {error: "Error in deleting comment"}, status: 400
        end
    end

    private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:forumthread_id, :User_id, :content)
    end
end
```

(GET still works, but POST has stopped working. I am not sure about the other methods, since those deal with existing comments, which I'm unable to create)

schema.rb:

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# This file is the source Rails uses to define your schema when running `bin/rails
# db:schema:load`. When creating a new database, `bin/rails db:schema:load` tends to
# be faster and is potentially less error prone than running all of your
# migrations from scratch. Old migrations may fail to apply correctly if those
# migrations use external dependencies or application code.
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2023_01_17_054548) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "User_id", null: false
    t.integer "forumthread_id", null: false
    t.string "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["User_id"], name: "index_comments_on_User_id"
    t.index ["forumthread_id"], name: "index_comments_on_forumthread_id"
  end

  create_table "forum_threads", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "User_id", null: false
    t.string "title"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "tag"
    t.index ["User_id"], name: "index_forum_threads_on_User_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "bio"
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #Routes
  get 'users/s/:username', to: "users#search"
  get 'users/:username/comments', to: "users#comments"
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
  resources :forum_threads, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
    resources :comments, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
  end
end
```

The function on my front-end that sends the POST request:

```
const user_id = useSelector(state => state.id);
    const threadID = useParams().id;
    // console.log("Thread ID: ", threadID, "User ID: ", user_id, "Content: ", content);
    //Creates new comment
    const handleCreateComment = (event) => {
        if (!isContentError) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ User_id: user_id, forumthread_id: threadID, content: content })
            };
            fetch('https://highgear.herokuapp.com/forum_threads/' + threadID + "/comments", requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => refreshCreate(data))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.alert("Error: Please enter a longer comment");
        }
    }
```

(Even if forumthread_id, User_id, and content are all correct, it still doesn't work. Not to mention, it still worked on LocalHost).

Output of Heroku logs when I send a POST request:

```
2023-01-18T04:32:47.335761+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-18T04:32:47.335689 #4]  INFO -- : [bd8c3745-fffc-485c-ba6d-42ff8dbfff91] Started POST "/forum_threads/1/comments" for 137.132.217.46 at 2023-01-18 04:32:47 +0000

2023-01-18T04:32:47.336418+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-18T04:32:47.336374 #4]  INFO -- : [bd8c3745-fffc-485c-ba6d-42ff8dbfff91] Processing by CommentsController#create as */*

2023-01-18T04:32:47.336455+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-18T04:32:47.336430 #4]  INFO -- : [bd8c3745-fffc-485c-ba6d-42ff8dbfff91]   Parameters: {"User_id"=>1, "forumthread_id"=>"1", "content"=>"<p>Test</p>", "forum_thread_id"=>"1", "comment"=>{"User_id"=>1, "forumthread_id"=>"1", "content"=>"<p>Test</p>"}}

2023-01-18T04:32:47.394387+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-18T04:32:47.394318 #4]  INFO -- : [bd8c3745-fffc-485c-ba6d-42ff8dbfff91] Completed 400 Bad Request in 58ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 36.8ms | Allocations: 3324)

2023-01-18T04:32:47.398408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/forum_threads/1/comments" host=highgear.herokuapp.com request_id=bd8c3745-fffc-485c-ba6d-42ff8dbfff91 fwd="137.132.217.46" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=60ms status=400 bytes=620 protocol=https
```

[Output in console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMQrk.png)

Here's the Heroku logs for a successful GET request to the comments controller:

```
2023-01-19T07:19:25.988821+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/forum_threads/2/comments" host=highgear.herokuapp.com request_id=c9293482-735d-4039-8b40-842bd2bff8ce fwd="137.132.220.33" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=304 bytes=612 protocol=https

2023-01-19T07:19:25.924581+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-19T07:19:25.924514 #4]  INFO -- : [5e0341e6-b66a-4a79-9d33-03050c8933c5] Started GET "/users/2" for 137.132.220.33 at 2023-01-19 07:19:25 +0000

2023-01-19T07:19:25.925293+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-19T07:19:25.925219 #4]  INFO -- : [5e0341e6-b66a-4a79-9d33-03050c8933c5] Processing by UsersController#show as */*

2023-01-19T07:19:25.925308+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-19T07:19:25.925285 #4]  INFO -- : [5e0341e6-b66a-4a79-9d33-03050c8933c5]   Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}

2023-01-19T07:19:25.927371+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-19T07:19:25.927325 #4]  INFO -- : [5e0341e6-b66a-4a79-9d33-03050c8933c5] Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Allocations: 271)

2023-01-19T07:19:25.964027+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-19T07:19:25.963965 #4]  INFO -- : [c9293482-735d-4039-8b40-842bd2bff8ce] Started GET "/forum_threads/2/comments" for 137.132.220.33 at 2023-01-19 07:19:25 +0000

2023-01-19T07:19:25.964537+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-19T07:19:25.964491 #4]  INFO -- : [c9293482-735d-4039-8b40-842bd2bff8ce] Processing by CommentsController#index as */*

2023-01-19T07:19:25.964565+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-19T07:19:25.964537 #4]  INFO -- : [c9293482-735d-4039-8b40-842bd2bff8ce]   Parameters: {"forum_thread_id"=>"2"}

2023-01-19T07:19:25.986038+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-01-19T07:19:25.985982 #4]  INFO -- : [c9293482-735d-4039-8b40-842bd2bff8ce] Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 20.1ms | Allocations: 210)
```

Please comment if you need any more information.

EDIT: Here's some more information on the forumthreads model:

forum_threads_controller:

```
class ForumThreadsController < ApplicationController
    #GET /ForumThreads [Get all threads]
    def index
        @threads = ForumThread.all
        render json: @threads
    end

    #GET /ForumThreads/:id [Get a specific thread by its ID]
    def show
        @thread = ForumThread.find(params[:id])
        render json: @thread
    end

    #POST /ForumThreads [Create a thread] 
    def create
        @thread = ForumThread.new(thread_params)
        if @thread.save
            render json: @thread
        else
            render error: {error: "Error in creating thread"}, status: 400
        end
    end

    #PUT /ForumThreads/:id [Update a thread]
    def update
        @thread = ForumThread.find(params[:id])
        if @thread
            @thread.update(thread_params)
            render json: {message: "Thread successfully updated"}, status: 200
        else
            render error: {error: "Error in updating thread"}, status: 400
        end
    end

    #DELETE /ForumThreads/:id [Delete a thread]
    def destroy
        @thread = ForumThread.find(params[:id])
        @comments = Comment.where("ForumThread_id = ?", params[:id])
        if @thread
            for @comment in @comments
                @comment.destroy
            end
            @thread.destroy
            render json: {message: "Thread successfully deleted"}, status: 200
        else
            render error: {error: "Error in deleting thread"}, status: 400
        end
    end

    private
    def thread_params
        params.require(:forum_thread).permit(:User_id, :title, :description, :tag)
    end
end
```

forum_thread.rb:

```
class ForumThread < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :User
end
```

Comment: Should `User_id` in your fetch with a capital letter ? Also check your validations as the 400 is explicit from a failure to update / create in your controller .. Maybe add a bang to your methods: `@comment.save!` instead of `@comment.save` etc ...

Comment: All values inside params are strings. Even if they’ve been submitted as integers. For some reason, when you send a POST request, the `User_id` within params (Heroku logs), is an integer and the rest of the params as strings. Perhaps you could try converting the `user_id` into a string before submitting the form? Not 100% sure if it will solve the problem but it is worth trying no?

Answer (score 0):

By using `@comment.save` and handling all failures the same way, you are hiding the cause of the failure.

A better way is to transform you `create` method to something like:

```rb
    # POST /Comments [Create a comment]
    def create
      @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
      @comment.save!
      render json: @comment
    rescue ArgumentError, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => err
      render error: {message: err.message }, status: 400
    rescue => err
      render error: {message: err.message }, status: 500
    end
```

But by doing that, you end up having to handle failure cases for each route. You would prefer to have global handlers for your exceptions. Example:

```rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    rescue_from Exception, with: :render_error
    rescue_from ArgumentError, with: :render_bad_request
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :render_bad_request
    
    # ...
  
    # POST /Comments [Create a comment]
    def create
      @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
      @comment.save!
      render json: @comment
    end

    # ...
    private 
     
    def render_bad_request(err)
      render error: {message: err.message }, status: 400
    end

    def render_error(err)
      render error: {message: err.message }, status: 500
    end
end
```

These global error handlers can be put in a parent class that each controller inherits from to make this even more reusable:

```rb
class BaseController < ApplicationController
    rescue_from Exception, with: :render_error
    rescue_from ArgumentError, with: :render_bad_request
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :render_bad_request
    
    private 
     
    def render_bad_request(err)
      render error: {message: err.message }, status: 400
    end

    def render_error(err)
      render error: {message: err.message }, status: 500
    end
end

class CommentsController < BaseController
    # POST /Comments [Create a comment]
    def create
      @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
      @comment.save!
      render json: @comment
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I added the error handling part, and it gives me the following error:
`Validation failed: Forumthread must exist`, even though the forumthread does exist. Any suggestions?
I've added more information about the forumthread model in the original post.

Comment: @SaumyaShah honestly for what I see, your react call and models seem rights. if Rails says `Validation failed: Forumthread must exist` it probably means that... the `Forumthread` does not actually exists ;-) Please double-check that the `forum_thread` with `id=1` exists. I cannot be of much more help without having access to your app/db (obviously not a good idea).

Comment: Wait a moment: it seems that you are passing the `forum_thread_id` as a string instead of an integer. Have you tried to do something like `parseInt(threadID)` in the construction of your POST payload (React side)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I double-checked that the forum thread does indeed exist ([here's a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/jBzHLVA)). I also tried parsing the id to int on React side, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @SaumyaShah very difficult to debug without beeing on your runtime but I spotted two more this: on the `ForumThread` class, you should have a `has_many :comments` AND `forumthread_id` columns on the `comments` table should be renamed to `forum_thread_id`. Maybe one of these two (if not both) are the source of your issues.